# How to hide the windows Default context menu in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, contextmenu

I had developed a `WPF` application which have full screen facility. But when my window is at it full screen mode, the custom context menu in the `Datagrid` is not working properly, whenever I right click on the `Datagrid` (while having the `Window State Full Screen`) the custom context disappears in a fraction of a second and  the default context menu as shown below, appears on the `Datagrid`.

```
____________
| Restore  |
|          |
| Move     |
|          |
| Size     |
|          | 
| Minimize |
|          |
| Maximize |
|          |
| Close    |
|__________|
```

So, I want to hide this menu when my window is in full screen mode. The `context menu` is working fine for the `Maximize` and `Normal` window state.

Code snippet:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top"  Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

            <MenuItem Header="_View">
               <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False" Header="Full Screen" Checked="FullScreen_Checked" Unchecked="FullScreen_Unchecked"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help">
                <MenuItem Header="View Help">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="Resources/question-icon.png"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <Separator></Separator>
                <MenuItem Header="About" Click="About_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="Resources/info6.png"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
<DataGrid Padding="3" BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsCoreData}}"   SelectionUnit="FullRow" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Data"  Margin="0,5,0,28">

<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextKeyTerm" IsEnabled="False" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Key Term" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked" Tag="0" />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextKeyTermDescription" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Key Term Description" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked" Tag="1"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextShortHand" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Short Hand" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked" Tag="2"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextRule" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Header="Rule" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked" Tag="3"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextPartM" IsCheckable="True"   Header="Part" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked"  Tag="4"  />
                    <MenuItem x:Name="ContextSectionM" IsCheckable="True"   Header="Section" Unchecked="ContextMenu_Unchecked" Checked="ContextMenu_Checked" Tag="5"  />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>



private void FullScreen_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            this.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = true;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            this.ShowTitleBar = false;
        }

        private void FullScreen_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            this.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = false;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            this.ShowTitleBar = true;
        }
```

Comment: Well, it would be helpful if you showed us your code, don't you think?

Comment: I do not think that the code will help much. I make my window fullscreen using `this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;`
            `this.IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize = false;`
            `this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;`
            `this.ShowTitleBar = true;` and if i right click any part of the window the default context menu appears as defined earlier.

Comment: `But when my window at it full screen mode. The my custom context menu in datagrid not working, it comes and dis appear in a fraction of seconds and the default context menu`  We can totally figure it out from that statement... edit your question and show your code.

Comment: I had already put my code snippet now what will be the solution.??